# Which one is most optimal way to get the document on mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

1>  db.people.find ( { $and : [ {name : { $gt : "D" } }, {name : { $regex : "a" } } ] } );

2>  db.people.find( { name : { $gt : "D",  $regex : "a" } } );

both MongoDB query give the same document in mongo shell. 
I want to know which one is OPTIMAL  and why ??

Comment: I don't think you would notice a performance difference for either one, but the second one is easier to read -- at least for me. Using `$regex` cannot use indices though unless it starts with `^`

Answer (score 0):

Both should be the same. If you run explain on the 2nd query, you can see the following and the `$and` operator being used

```
> db.people.find( { name : { $gt : "D", $regex : "a" } } ).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.people",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : {
                                                "$gt" : "D"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : /a/
                                }
                        ]
                },
```